# Registering an application to URI scheme in Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows, registry, uri, msdn

I have a requirement to register a desktop application to a URI scheme (To be be able to open the application from another application using URI).

I followed this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and have something like below.

```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
      -->myappname
         -->shell
            -->open
               -->command
                  (Default) = "c:\pathtomyapp\app.exe"
```

Now to test if this works as expected, I have a html code that basically does this

```
    <html><body>
    <a href="myappname:">MyApp</a>
    </body></html>
```

But clicking on the hyperlink "MyApp" doesnt seem to open the application. Gives error "no apps are installed to open this type of link" Could you please point me to the missing piece?

Update: This works in Win10 but not on Win8

Thanks!